# Component is not receiving the value from another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am having difficulty receiving value from another component. So what I am trying to do is that I am taking in an input value which is the stock ticker from the user in `serachBar.js` and passing the the ticker value to `salesModel.js` where the stock data will be displayed in a table format. However, before displaying the data I am sending the value to `StockData.js` where the API retrives the information based on the user input and sends the data back to the salesModel.js file to be displayed. However, for reason I cant pass the value from the `searchBar.js` file to`salesModel.js`file. I have places the code the below for both components and also thank you in advance for any advice I would really appreciate it.

**Searchbar.js**

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          inputTicker:''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        

    }

    // handleSubmit (event) {
    handleSubmit =  event => {

        event.preventDefault();
        const { inputTicker } = this.state; 

        console.log("Current value?", inputTicker);


    }

    handleChange = event => {
    // handleChange(event) {
        
        // event.preventDefault();
        
        console.log("Taking in value:",event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            inputTicker: event.target.value
        });
        // console.log("State:", JSON.parse(this.state.inputTicker));   
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            <div> 
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className="search-container">
                    <span className="search-icon-btn" >
                        <button className="search-icon-btn" 
                                value="Submit" 
                                type="submit" 
                        >
                            <i className="fa fa-search" ></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <div className="search-input">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            className="search-bar" 
                            placeholder="Search ticker symbol..."
                            value={this.state.inputTicker}
                            onChange= {this.handleChange}
                        />

                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </form>

            </div> 

        )
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**salesModel.js**

```
class salesModel extends Component{
// function salesModel (props) {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
          ticker:''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("passed the value:",this.props.inputTicker);
        
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <div className="salesModel" >
                <h1>Price to Sales Model (PS)</h1>
                    <table className="table mt-5">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Ticker</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>PE Ratio</th>
                                <th>Market Cap</th>
                                <th>Shares Outstanding</th>
                                <th>Beta</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                        <tbody>
                            {/* <SearchBar handleSubmit={(input)=> this.setState({ticker: input})}/> */}
                            {/* <StockData ticker = "AAPL" /> */}
                            {/* <StockData ticker = {this.props.inputTicker} /> */}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default salesModel;
```

I have tried calling the `<SearchBar handleSubmit={(input)=> this.setState({ticker: input})}/>` and setting the value as to ticker but for some reason that didn't work as well. I have tried to use the props.inputTicker from the searchBar.js file but for some reason it would give me an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0`. Honestly I have been stuck at this problem for sometime any help would be greatly appreciative thank you.

Comment: You want to pass salesModal data to searchbar ?

Comment: No, I don't want to pass any data to `searchBar` instead I want to retrieve input data from `searchBar` to `salesModel`

Comment: Ok, let me create and sandbox and an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is a parent component that takes care of the state for both of them.

In this example the `App.js` is the parent and the `SearchBar.js`and `SalesModal.js` are the children

Here is an [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-wildflower-0crwx?file=/src/SalesModal.js:34-44)

```
// App.js (parent component)
import React, { useState } from "react";

import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import SalesModal from "./SalesModal";

const App = () => {
  const [searchBarText, setSearchBarText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SearchBar
        searchBarText={searchBarText}
        setSearchBarText={setSearchBarText}
      />
      <SalesModal searchBarText={searchBarText} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```
// SearchBar.js (child component)
import React from "react";

const SearchBar = ({ searchBarText, setSearchBarText }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={searchBarText}
      onChange={(e) => setSearchBarText(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

```
// SalesModal.js (child component)
import React from "react";

const SalesModal = ({ searchBarText }) => {
  return <div> searchBar Text: {searchBarText}</div>;
};

export default SalesModal;
```